# Understanding the sample list within this function

Tags: python

I'm trying to better understand the mechanics from this code from the edx intro to python course. I've marked the part that I am confused about.

To reframe the question:

Why can't I set it to

```
my_min = sample_list[10]
```

or

```
my_min = sample_list[0,1]
```

############# Sample Solution

```
def _find_min_sample_(sample_list):
    # Initially set the first element
    # of the list as the minimum
    my_min = sample_list[0]     # <---this is where i am confused.
    # Iterate through the list
    for item in sample_list:
        # Compare each item from the list
        # to the current minimum. If the item is smaller
        # than your current minimum then set that item
        # to be your current minimum instead
        if item < my_min:
            my_min = item
    # finally return the minimum value
    return my_min 

_find_min_sample_([-10,8,9,7])
```

Comment: you *could* set `my_min` to `sample_list[valid_index]` or `sample_list[0:1]` or any other single value from the list, since you check all the values

Comment: @Chris_Rands, but the input list only has 4 items.. seems like OP doesn't understand that it's an integer indexer.

Comment: could you elaborate more on what an integer indexer is? I'm obviously new to python and am unfamiliar with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `my_min = sample_list[10]` it will fail if there are less than 11 elements in your list.

You're (almost) sure that there is at least one element in your list, therefore you use `sample_list[0]`.